# How do i get info from this c# for a game mod

Tags: c#, game-development

[image: Help]

[image: help][image: Help]

I want to get the info from FilteredNickName string. Can Anyone help me out?

Comment: We don't have a clue what FilteredNickName contains, so we can't really help.  It seems to be a string, so one can guess that you would probably need to split it and/or use a REGEX.

Comment: Post some example strings .

Comment: Nothing to do with the question, but there's no need to post images with code.
You can just paste your code as text, indented by 4 spaces, and it will be properly highlighted.